# How can I view item-details of items posted in Chat

Tags: path-of-exile

I guess this is very simple, but I could not find a way to do this yet.

Often people post Items in the chat. If I mouse hover over them or right click them, nothing happens. How can I see a popup window with item-details in Chat, like I see it when I hover with the mouse over a dropped item in the game?

Is this a setting somewhere which is turned of by default? Or do i need a key-combination?

Comment: It's been a while I played - have you made sure to first have chat opened?

Comment: What do you mean by opened, it is  always there. i See it always on the left side,  is there something additional i have to do? I am used to the Chat of guildwars2, its nearly the same,  only i cant See Details of posted items in poe

Comment: Apologies, I meant actually opening chat, by pressing the enter key. As far as I remember you had to do that before you can type in chat.

Comment: Ok, must try that when I am at home. Actually i did no try to type something in the chat yet, just wanted to view the items that other people posted. Maybe i can only view them, when i switch to "type-mode".

Comment: I am absolutely sure you can only view the details in "type-mode".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to view item details in chat first you must make sure to have chat opened.
Below you can see me trying to hover over the item, however no details appeared. (Steam Screenshots do not show the in-game cursor) 
[image: Trying to hover over items in chat]

However once I opened chat and hovered over the item the details appeared.
[image: Item details in chat]

Comment: Also worth noting that if YOU would like to post items in chat you ctrl-alt-left click them from your inventory.